# How to get all order id with current status as "completed" in prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop

I am trying to get all order ids, i am not sure to use function or execute sql query
which one is fast considering the performance ?

Is their any way get it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very light query, even if you have tens of thousands of orders.

```
$orders = Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT `id_order` FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'orders`');

$ids = array_map(function ($row) {
    return $row['id_order'];
}, $orders);
```

Comment: Thankyou , can you please take a look at this question related to prestashop ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63516766/how-can-i-find-responsible-code-for-resend-email-in-order-view-page-admin-in

Answer (score 0):

```
$orders= Order::getOrderIdsByStatus($id_status);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

```
$OrderIds = array_column(Order::getOrdersWithInformations(),'id_order' );
```

Comment: Thankyou , can you please take a look at this question related to prestashop ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63516766/how-can-i-find-responsible-code-for-resend-email-in-order-view-page-admin-in

Comment: this query will get many not really needed columns and is much slower than getting just one field you need

Comment: We only use a specific Prestashop function. Without having to create any other